# Suggestion for books about mathematics of quantum entanglement and computation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, resource-recommendations, quantum-computer

I am reading book called *Mathematics of Quantum Computation* by Ranee K. Brylinski and Goong Chen, and it's really what I need since I am working on quantum entanglement and this kind of stuff, but the problem is that I found the book really vague and I can't really understand it. I wonder if someone can have suggestions about new book or book that can give me a building materials so I can understand this book.

Comment: Please read [our guidelines for resource-recommendation questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4697/are-resource-recommendations-allowed/) carefully. As currently phrased, your question is too broad for our format - you need to be much more specific as to what aspects of the book you already have you don't understand and what level of prerequisites you're looking for.

Comment: That said, your claim that you find the Brylinski & Chen book "vague" is an enormous red flag. That is an intensely technical book which uses extremely precise language; it might have many failings that make it hard to use as an introductory text, but "vague" isn't one of them.

Comment: I understand what what are you saying but honestly the book is vague for me i have read pure math books before but when i read this book even simplest propositions is hard to understand . its mostly because i lack the math background , i am just wondering if there is book about the same subject which explain the same things with more details .

Comment: "Hard to understand" is not the same thing as "vague", but unless you give more details about how exactly you found the book confusing, as well as your current background, then it will be extremely hard to give answers that are more useful than the closely related thread I'm linking to below.

Comment: i only need the first chapter of book and i am interested in theorems about entanglement but i cant even understand the propositions i thinks maybe because its too advance for me so i will appreciate if some one recommend book about same subject with more detail maybe a book which start form basics . but the real problem is i can understand the proofs in the book but i don't get the theorems and proposition so basically  by looking at the proofs i am trying to understand what is the proposition .